# How does this largest prime factor finding algorithm work?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, primes

I saw this YouTube video online where this guy finds the largest prime factor of a number using a seemingly simple approach, but I don't quite understand the math of it. Here's the link https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5kv9q7qgvlI
The code -

```
n=1234 # Some number whose largest factor I want to find
i=2 # It seems that he tries to start from the smallest prime number
while i**2<n: # I don't understand this part where he checks if the square of variable is less than the target number 
    while n%i==0: # I know this checks if n is divisible by i
        n/=i 
    i+=1 # increments i's value
print(n)
```

I know that this code works, but why? I get the last two lines, but why is it necessary to check if the square of variable i is less than n?

Comment: I guess you miss `i+=1` at the outer while loop?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63276/is-a-prime-factor-of-a-number-always-less-than-its-square-root/63278 may be helpful. I am not sure whether the algorithm is correct or not because `i` is always `2`.

Comment: run the algorithm for 49 or 25

Comment: It does work for all real positive numbers; none of the test cases I have tried have failed.

Answer (score 2):

If your number `N` is divisible by `I` (in other terms, `I` being a factor of `N`), and `I` is greater than `sqrt(N)`, then there must be another factor of `N`, call it `J = N/I`, being smaller than `sqrt(N)`.

If you exhaustively searched all potential factors up to `I`, you must have already found `J`, so you covered that factorization earlier.

We are looking for the largest **prime** factor, so the question remains whether the final `N` when terminating the loop is a prime number.

Whenever we encountered a factor of `N`, we divided `N` by this factor, so when considering a potential factor `I`, we can be sure that the current `N` won't have any factors below `I` any more.

Can the final `N` when terminating the loop be composed from more than one factor (i.e. not being prime)?

No.

If N isn't prime, it must be composed from `K` and `L` (`N = K * L`), and `K` and `L` must be both bigger than `sqrt(N)`, otherwise we would have divided by `K` or `L` in an earlier step. But multiplying two numbers, each bigger than `sqrt(N)`, will always be bigger than `N`, violating `N = K * L`.

So, assuming that the final `N` wasn't prime, runs into a contradiction, and thus we can be sure that the final `N` is a factor of the original `N`, and that this factor is indeed a prime number.

**Caveats with the original code (thanks JohanC)**:

The original code checks for `I` being strictly less than `SQRT(N)` (`while i**2<n`). That will miss cases like N=9 where its square root 3 must be included in the iteration. So, this should better read `while i**2<=n`.

And the code risks some inaccuracies:

- Using floating-point division (`/=` operator instead of `//=`) might give inexact results. This applies to Python, while in languages like Java, `/=` would be fine.
- In Python, raising an integer to the power of 2 (`while i**2<=n`) seems to guarantee exact integer arithmetic, so that's ok in the Python context. In languages like Java, I'd recommend not to use the `pow()` function, as that typically uses floating-point arithmetic with the risk of inexact results, but to simply write `i*i`.

Comment: You didn't explain why the code doesn't work for numbers such as 9, 75, etc. `while i**2 <= n` and `while n > i and n % i == 0:` might help.  Also, using integer division (`n //= i`) might be useful for some large numbers where floating point division can go wrong.

Comment: @JohanC You're right, there seems to be a bug in the original code. Instead of `while i**2<n` it should be `while i**2<=n` I didn't realize that. It shows up if the highest prime factor occurs more than once, as in 9 = 3*3 or 75 = 3*5*5. And yes, with Python's two division operators, the `//` division is indeed the safer option. I'll add a paragraph to my answer.

Comment: You still need ` n > i` in `while n > i and n % i == 0:` to avoid returning 1 as an answer in all cases where the highest factor has a multiplicity larger than 1. `while i**2<=n` only helps to prevent return `p**2` when the highest factor has a multiplicity 2.